# extracting facebook photo id from a LONG url

Tags: php, regex, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, preg-match

I have searched this website on how to extract facebook id from url that starts from photo.php?fbid= but i have a long url and know how to get photo id

Example1 : photo.php?fbid=10151987845617397 (the complete url is stored in the $url variable which is checked using preg_match i believe)

```
!preg_match("|^http(s)?://(www.)?facebook.com/photo.php(.*)?$|i", $url) || !$pid
```

the above code fetches facebook id 10151987845617397 and puts it in the variable $pid.

If I have a long url, how can i change the code?
Here is the url
Example2 : https://www.facebook.com/nokia/photos/a.338008237396.161268.36922302396/10151987845617397/?type=1&theater
In the above url 10151987845617397 is the photo id that i need to capture and put it in variable $pid.

what changes do i need to do in the preg_match string?

In other words to get the photoid 10151987845617397 as output in the $pid variable:

For url facebookcom/photo.php?fbid=10151987845617397
The syntax is !preg_match("|^http(s)?://(www.)?facebook.com/photo.php(.*)?$|i", $url) || !$pid

So for url facebookcom/nokia/photos/a.338008237396.161268.36922302396/10151987845617397/?type=1&theater
What would be the syntax

Please help
Thanks

Comment: "the above code fetches facebook id 10151987845617397 and puts it in the variable $pid." not it doesn't, remove the `!` and it may will.

Comment: The script is working fine. What I need is a new syntax. How to write a new preg_match statement or how to change the preg_match statement given in the question if the url is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution and quite readable: Use the entire string as a regex, use `()` around what you want to match:

```
// $tmp[1] = www or nothing
// $tmp[2] = "user" (i.e nokia)
// $tmp[3] = album id?
// $tmp[4] = photos
// $tmp[5] = Long url as requested
function extract_id_from_album_url($url) {
    preg_match('/https?:\/\/(www.)?facebook\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]*)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]*)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]*)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)(\/\?type=1&theater\/)?/i', $url, $tmp);

    return isset($tmp[5]) ? $tmp[5] : false;
}
```

Backslashes are needed to ensure the `.` is seen as a literal (and not regex syntax). Questionmarks to allow optional urls. Using more regex syntax can make the matching "query" much shorter and extendable, but also makes it harder to read.

Comment: I am not a programmer and may not understand. However, I wish to tell you that the nokia url is just a sample url. The actual url will be posted by the user.

Like in the first url photo.php(.*)?$|i", $url
the url is coming from $url

can this portion be changed if the user puts a url which is different and longer?

Please probe if im not explaining it properly

Thanks

Comment: Excuse me, this is hard to explain to a non programmer, but I hope it helps. A user can now provide almost any url and the regex tries to find matching "groups". `http://facebook.com/user3549869/movies` will not work, as it needs to look for "photo" album. You can use additional `()` group matching if you want. I hope it is more clear?

Comment: thank you for your reply. i am not a hardcore programmer but i can understand codes a bit and i can make changes to suit my needs with little bit of googling. I wish to tell you that the user will always give photo urls. The script which im using is hardcoded to work with url that starts with facebook<dot>com/photo.php?fbid=10151987845617397 and i want the user should supply url that facebook now uses for photo urls which is the long one. please reply if this is possible. I can send you the entire script/facebook php files to look at if you want. appreciate your help